# Having trouble with promise inside async function

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, appwrite

having a real problem with getting this code to work. I have everything set up working great with Appwrite. I'm getting a response back from the server, but in my promise.then it finishes the other code and returns undefined from  the login function. so then the post async function is sending a blank array in the try block. I've tried setting this code up every way I can think of but it never works. Sorry, i'm still trying to wrap my head around the promises and async js.

```
import { Appwrite } from 'appwrite';

export async function post({ locals, request }) {
const { email, password } = await request.json();

function login() {
    // add logic to authenticate user with external service here
    const sdk = new Appwrite();

    sdk
        .setEndpoint('https://') // API Endpoint
        .setProject('') // project ID
    ;

let promise = sdk.account.createSession(email, password);

    let userLogin;
    promise.then(function (response) {
    console.log(response); // Success
        userLogin = response.providerUid;
          console.log(userLogin);
    }, function (error) {
     console.log(error); // Failure
    });
    console.log('login.json.js', { email, password: !!password });

console.log(userLogin);
    return userLogin;
}

try {
    const user = login();
    locals.user = user;

    return {
        status: 200
    };
} catch (error) {
    const message = `Error in endpoint /api/login.json: ${error}`;
    return {
        status: 500,
        body: message
    };
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning `userLogin` in `login` before it's even populated in the asynchronous `promise.then` chain

Also, since you're currently handling the rejection in your `promise.then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` that would mean any rejection is handled inside `login` and your try/catch (once written correctly) would never have an error to catch since `login` handled it already

One more potential issue - if `const { email, password } = await request.json();` rejects, then the `error` will be thrown to whatever called `post` - is that what you want? or did that also need to be handled inside `post`?

Anyway here's how to fix your code:

```
import { Appwrite } from 'appwrite';

export async function post({ locals, request }) {
    // note: if this throws then the error will be handled by whatever calls `post`
    const { email, password } = await request.json();

    function login() {
        // add logic to authenticate user with external service here
        const sdk = new Appwrite();

        sdk
            .setEndpoint('https://') // API Endpoint
            .setProject('') // project ID
        ;
        const promise = sdk.account.createSession(email, password);
        return promise.then(function(response) {
            let userLogin = response.providerUid;
            return userLogin;
            // or without redundant `userLogin` variable
            // return response.providerUid;
        });
    }

    try {
        const user = await login();
        locals.user = user;

        return { status: 200 };
    } catch (error) {
        const message = `Error in endpoint /api/login.json: ${error}`;
        return { status: 500, body: message };
    }
}
```

Or, making `login` async

```
import { Appwrite } from 'appwrite';

export async function post({ locals, request }) {
    // note: if this throws then the error will be handled by whatever calls `post`
    const { email, password } = await request.json();

    async function login() {
        // add logic to authenticate user with external service here
        const sdk = new Appwrite();

        sdk
            .setEndpoint('https://') // API Endpoint
            .setProject('') // project ID
        ;

        let response = await sdk.account.createSession(email, password);
        let userLogin = response.providerUid;
        return userLogin;
    }

    try {
        const user = await login();
        locals.user = user;

        return {
            status: 200
        };
    } catch (error) {
        const message = `Error in endpoint /api/login.json: ${error}`;
        return {
            status: 500,
            body: message
        };
    }
}
```

Or, removing inner Login function completely

```
import { Appwrite } from 'appwrite';

export async function post({ locals, request }) {
    // note: if this throws then the error will be handled by whatever calls `post`
    const { email, password } = await request.json();
    try {
        const sdk = new Appwrite();

        sdk.setEndpoint('https://') // API Endpoint
            .setProject(''); // project ID

        const response = await sdk.account.createSession(email, password);
        console.log(response); // Success
        locals.user = response.providerUid;
        return { status: 200 };
    } catch (error) {
        const message = `Error in endpoint /api/login.json: ${error}`;
        return { status: 500, body: message };
    }
}
```